# How to make the label go up after clicking with css?

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

I want to make a form when on clicked the label would go up 15px and you can write the text, but I can't figure out how to do it with my current code. I think the problem is how I select the label and input.

I tried these ways:

```
.form-row-field-input:focus ~ label, 
.form-row-field-input:valid ~ label {
top: -12px;
left: 0;
font-size: 12px;
color: #003333;
font-weight: bold;}

input[type=text]:focus~label {
display:block;
color: black;
top: -20px;
font-size: 14px;}
```

```
<div class="form-inputs">
<form action="" method="POST">
<div class="form-row">
      <span class="form-row-number">01</span>
      <label for="POST-name" class="form-row-field">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-row-field-input">
</div>
<div class="form-row">
      <span class="form-row-number">02</span>
      <label for="POST-lastname" class="form-row-field">Last name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-row-field-input">
 </div>
 <div class="form-row">
        <span class="form-row-number">03</span>
        <label for="POST-email" class="form-row-field">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-row-field-input">
   </div>
       <input class="form-btn" type="submit" value="Get it">
  </form>
  </div><!--end-->
```

/** CSS **/

```
.form-inputs {
padding: 40px;
flex: 60%;
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
align-content: center;
justify-content: center;
position: relative;
 }
.form-btn {
margin: 20px 0px;
background-color: #f6fe00;
color: black;
padding: 10px 40px;
font-weight: 700;
border: none;
cursor: pointer;
 }
.form-row {
border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
padding: 10px 0px;
position: relative;
}
.form-row-number {
color: #8f63ff;
padding-right: 10px;
}
.form-row-field {
color: #9b91f5;
position: absolute;
pointer-events: none;
transition: 0.5s;
top: 10px;
margin-left: 1em;
}
.form-row-field-input {
background-color: inherit;
border: none;
display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
transition: 0.5s;
margin-left: 1.5em;
}
```

I expect that when clicked on input, the label would go up with a transition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general sibling selector in CSS that you're using can only target elements that come AFTER, so since the label comes before the input in your HTML, it's not actually applying the CSS.

You can get the intended effect simply be moving the label element after the input. Google's Material UI also takes this approach in order to keep it primarily CSS to achieve the intended visual effect.

Here it is with the label elements moved to after the input and slightly tweaked CSS:

```
<body>
    <div class="form-inputs">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="form-row">
                <span class="form-row-number">01</span>

                <input type="text" class="form-row-field-input">
                <label for="POST-name" class="form-row-field">First name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <span class="form-row-number">02</span>

                <input type="text" class="form-row-field-input">
                <label for="POST-lastname" class="form-row-field">Last name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <span class="form-row-number">03</span>

                <input type="text" class="form-row-field-input">
                <label for="POST-email" class="form-row-field">Email</label>
            </div>
            <input class="form-btn" type="submit" value="Get it">
        </form>
    </div>
    <!--end-->
</body>
```

```
  .form-inputs {
            padding: 40px;
            flex: 60%;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-content: center;
            justify-content: center;
            position: relative;
        }

        .form-btn {
            margin: 20px 0px;
            background-color: #f6fe00;
            color: black;
            padding: 10px 40px;
            font-weight: 700;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }

        .form-row {
            border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
            padding: 10px 0px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .form-row-number {
            color: #8f63ff;
            padding-right: 10px;
        }

        .form-row-field {
            color: #9b91f5;
            position: absolute;
            pointer-events: none;
            transition: 0.5s;
            top: 10px;
            margin-left: 1em;
        }

        .form-row-field-input {
            background-color: inherit;
            border: none;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            transition: 0.5s;
            margin-left: 1.5em;
        }

        .form-row-field-input:focus~label {
            top: -5px;
            font-size: 12px;
            color: #003333;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7urgeL60/

Comment: Thanks for your help and fast response time! I didn't expect it.

Comment: There is another problem now, when you write the text, the label turns back to the same position and it mixes with text and label. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Without using javascript, this starts to get a bit cumbersome but still possible to fix. You can use the css selector ```input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~label``` to continue applying the floating label style when the input is not showing a placeholder (ie. has actual values typed into the input box), but for this CSS selector to work you'll also have to add ```placeholder=" "``` to each input box. Here's the updated jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0k3xmaw6/3/

There is also one thing to be wary of - not all browsers support this pseudo-class: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder-shown